# Incorrect Shared Folder Path Being Generated

Tags: c#, asp.net

In my code:

```
protected readonly string DropFolder = @"\\SharedFolder\Subfolder";
```

In ILSpy:

```
protected readonly string DropFolder = "\\\\SharedFolder\\Subfolder";
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some characters are stored as the corresponding escape sequences in CIL, and `\`  is one of them (stored as `\\`). These two strings are equal: `@"\" == "\\"`.

Read [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9113440/where-can-i-find-a-list-of-escaped-characters-in-msil-string-constants) for more details.